# How to send Ajax request on interval depending on response

Tags: jquery, ajax

How to send ajax request at internal time but also depending on response? If response satisfies some condition, it no long sends ajax.  Thank you so much!

Sample code

```
function send_ajax_on_interval(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        url: ...
        data: ...
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            status = response['stat_code'];
            if (status == 0) {
               // stop sending requests, otherwise continuously send in every 5 seconds
         
        },
        complete:function(){
        
        },
        error: function () {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: On success (and pass `if`) use `setTimeout(send_ajax_on_interval, 5000)` - you could use `setInterval` but there's a chance it will cascade (if your ajax request takes more than a few milliseconds) and you end up making multiple simultaneous calls - so better to queue next one when first finishes etc.

Comment: There may be better solutions than frequent polling, eg using websockets

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the interval within a variable, clear it and reinitialize it;

```
 var ajaxInterval;
 ajaxInterval = setInterval(send_ajax_on_interval(),5000);
```

And if the condition is true, clear it

```
if(status == 0){
     clearInterval(ajaxInterval);
}
```